# Dask map_partitions() prints `partition_info` as None

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

I'm trying to use DataFrame.map_partitions() from Dask to apply a function on each partition. The function takes in input a list of values and have to return the rows of the dataframe partition that contains these values, on a specific column (using `loc()` and `isin()`).
The issue is that I get this error:

**"index = partition_info['number'] - 1 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"**

When I print partition_info, it prints `None` hundreds of times (but I only have 60 elements in the loop so we expect only 60 prints), is it normal to print `None` because it's a child process or am I missing something with partition_info? I cannot find useful information on that.

```py
def apply_f(df, barcodes_per_core: List[List[str]], partition_info=None):
    print(partition_info)
    index = partition_info['number'] - 1
    indexes = barcodes_per_core[index]
    return df.loc[df['barcode'].isin(indexes)]

df = from_pandas(df, npartitions=nb_cores)
dfs_per_core = df.map_partitions(apply_f, barcodes_per_core, meta=df)
dfs_per_core = dfs_per_core.compute(scheduler='processes')
```

=> Doc of partition_info at the end of this [page](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why things are not working on your end, one potential thing is that you are re-using `df` multiple times. Here's a MWE that works:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=["a"])

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

def my_func(d, x, partition_info=None):
    print(x, partition_info)

ddf.map_partitions(my_func, 3, meta=df.head()).compute(scheduler='processes')
```